scrollIntoView with react is glitchy and unpredictable when using newest version of chrome, even more so while simulating mobile
I'm experiencing some crazy graphical glitches on my react app, specifically when I scroll elements into view.
Quick overview - the app is a portrait kiosk app where every 'stage' element is like a card filling up the whole screen, and as the user progresses the app's flow, cards scroll horizontally to the left or right (based on language), bringing the newest stage's card into view, and deleting the previous one when the scroll finishes.
Well ever since the chrome update a few days ago, things are barely working. Some stage are snapped back into when the current scroll ends, elements from different stages will suddenly appear at random positions on the screen over other stages, and sometimes parts of a stage will not render properly, as if cut in half at an arbitrary position. Also on some stages, the onScrollComplete won't be called at all.
This is 10 times worse when I test the application using chrome's device simulator, 100 time worse when I do so with throttling.
I'm suspecting the chrome version itself, because other app are experiencing strange behaviors as well - such as chrome tab crashing ("oh snap" screen) if I log into and account using auth0 while the developer tools are opened, or the dev tools screen crashing when reloading the page after certain event, stuff like that.
Anyway,this is the relevant code:
Scrolling mechanism:
const stageElement = stageRefs.current[currentStage?.name].current

    if (!stageElement) {
      console.error(`Stage ${currentStage?.name} was not found in the DOM`)
      return
    }
    if (!scrolling) {
      setScrolling(true)
      stageElement.focus()
      stageElement.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
        block: 'start',
        inline: 'start'
      })
    }


On scroll complete hook:
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const useScrollCompletion = (scrollerRef, onComplete) => {
  const scrollEndTimer = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      clearTimeout(scrollEndTimer.current);
      
      scrollEndTimer.current = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('scroll complete')
        onComplete();
      }, 150);
    };

    const scrollerElement = scrollerRef.current;
    if (scrollerElement) {
      scrollerElement.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    }

    return () => {
      if (scrollerElement) {
        scrollerElement.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
      }
      clearTimeout(scrollEndTimer.current);
    };
  }, [scrollerRef, onComplete]);
};

export default useScrollCompletion;

Callbak used when scrolling is completed:
const onScrollComplete = () => {
    setScrolling(false)

    if (activeStages.some(stage => stage.name !== 'home')) {
      clearStages()
    }

    if (currentStage?.name === 'home' && activeStages.some(stage => stage.name !== 'home')) {
      clearStages()
    }
  }

(activeStages is a map representing currently mounted JSX objects.)
Thanks!
Oh and p.s -
Firefox works marvelously

The detection of the end scroll via a timeout is inherently flakey. I know this is common, but that 150ms value is dependant on browser implementation. Try to prove if this is the issue by lowering it or raising it in 20ms increments and trying it again. This is not a solution, as you could break another platform. For sure, a chrome upgrade may have caused variations. The real solution here is to remodel the complete callback mechanism to use intersection obserer.

Secondly, make sure onScrollComplete is wrapped with a useCallback

Ok about wrapping onscrollcomplete. As for you first reply - How can I use an intersection observer to know when the scroll completes? My stages aren't really intersecting anything, they just scroll away and to the screen's view. Are you talking about tracking the intersection with the viewport itself?

The intersection observer would be checking for the intersection between the stageElement and yes, the viewport. Its a pain in the ass to bind the IntersectionObserver API to React so I highly recommend https://github.com/thebuilder/react-intersection-observer#readme.

As long as it's the real solution.. I didn't like the whole polling check of the scrolling mechanism anyway. It's actually pretty incredible how the scrollIntoView mechanism has no state management, and is as limited as it is - time can't be set and afaict seem to be dependent on your processor's speed, for instances

Right exactly. Essentially "scroll" is a bit cursed to hook on for perf reasons and that's what bought about intersection observer which is an alternative event based approach. I would try first tweaking the timeout delay -- not as a solution, but just to try to prove a point its related to this.
